# How expensive are pthread_rwlock_*?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I just "accelerated" a piece of this code:

```
double value = ComputeSomething( point );
```

essentially like this:

```
double value;
pthread_rwlock_rdlock( & m_Mutex );
if( ! SmallCache.Find( point, & value ) ) {
    pthread_rwlock_unlock( & m_Mutex );
    double value = ComputeSomething( point );
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock( & m_Mutex );
    SmallCache.Add( point, value );
}
pthread_rwlock_unlock( & m_Mutex );
return value;
```

Cache hit is about 75%. Cache is a `std::list`; `SmallCache.Find` traverses it from `begin` to `end`. `SmallCache.Add` does `push_front` of new values and `pop_back` of old ones to keep the list fairly small, only 16 items. `ComputeSomething` is presumed to be moderately expensive.

The outcome of this acceleration (drumbeat) 5% slowdown.

Thus the questions: what could be the cause of the above slowdown? I suspect `pthread_rwlock_*`, although not sure. If the slowdown was indeed due to locking, how one can avoid that?

Comment: Depends on the architecture, and of course, "How much contention on the lock" - in other words, it may not be the LOCK itself (the calls to lock/unlock), but the fact that your threads are all waiting for the lock to be released...

Comment: And the relative cost of the computation vs. chasing 16 pointers  (and a heap allocation on cache miss).

Comment: I'd probably make it either an array or a vector instead of a list... ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: unfortunately when I run the application single-threaded I still observe slight slowdown, despite all the cache hits. Will try an array instead of the list next...

Comment: It would of course help to understand what `ComputeSomething` actually does.

Comment: How expensive is the computation? How expensive is searching the list?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: just did some profiling. `ComputeSomething` takes 2 microseconds/call, much faster than I expected. Perhaps caching is not the solution here...

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at the disassembly of the `pthread_rwlock_rdlock` and `pthread_rwlock_wrlock`, it's reasonably light-weight in the "fast case" (that is, there is no contention, we're able to take the lock with no difficulty) - about 20 instructions - one of which is a `cmpxchg` (so will ask any other processor to "release this cache-line"), but the rest are pretty simple/lightweight instructions.

Of course, if you have to wait, then you're in for a bit of a ride, but that's what you'd expect.

[And no, don't ask me EXACTLY how it works]

Below is the code for `rdlock`, but `wrlock` is pretty similar in complexity.

Code here:

```
  406760:   48 89 fa                mov    %rdi,%rdx
  406763:   90                      nop
  406764:   0f b6 47 20             movzbl 0x20(%rdi),%eax
  406768:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  40676a:   0f 8e 90 00 00 00       jle    406800 <__pthread_rwlock_rdlock+0xa0>   // May need to do stuff here

  406770:   83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
  406773:   88 47 20                mov    %al,0x20(%rdi)
  406776:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40677b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40677d:   8b 72 1c                mov    0x1c(%rdx),%esi
  406780:   f0 0f b1 3a             lock cmpxchg %edi,(%rdx)
  406784:   74 16                   je     40679c <__pthread_rwlock_rdlock+0x3c>
<---- Lock maybe taken!
Else wait... 
  406786:   48 8d 3a                lea    (%rdx),%rdi
  406789:   48 81 ec 80 00 00 00    sub    $0x80,%rsp
  406790:   e8 bb 34 00 00          callq  409c50 <__lll_lock_wait>
  406795:   48 81 c4 80 00 00 00    add    $0x80,%rsp

---> Maybe taken?
  40679c:   8b 72 18                mov    0x18(%rdx),%esi
  40679f:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  4067a1:   75 4c                   jne    4067ef <__pthread_rwlock_rdlock+0x8f>
<---- Take slow path.
 Else may still have taken the lock.
  4067a3:   8b 4a 14                mov    0x14(%rdx),%ecx
  4067a6:   85 c9                   test   %ecx,%ecx
  4067a8:   75 3e                   jne    4067e8 <__pthread_rwlock_rdlock+0x88>
<--- Nope, slow path
  4067aa:   8b 4a 04                mov    0x4(%rdx),%ecx
  4067ad:   8d 41 01                lea    0x1(%rcx),%eax
  4067b0:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4067b2:   89 42 04                mov    %eax,0x4(%rdx)
  4067b5:   0f 84 d5 00 00 00       je     406890 <__pthread_rwlock_rdlock+0x130>
 <--- Slow path, lock not taken.
  Else: Success, we have the lock, update number of times it's locked.
  4067bb:   90                      nop
  4067bc:   45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
  4067bf:   8b 72 1c                mov    0x1c(%rdx),%esi
  4067c2:   f0 ff 0a                lock decl (%rdx)
  4067c5:   74 16                   je     4067dd <__pthread_rwlock_rdlock+0x7d>
 <---- Lock been taken, return!
ELSE if necessary, call the wake function too. 
  4067c7:   48 8d 3a                lea    (%rdx),%rdi
  4067ca:   48 81 ec 80 00 00 00    sub    $0x80,%rsp
  4067d1:   e8 1a 35 00 00          callq  409cf0 <__lll_unlock_wake>
  4067d6:   48 81 c4 80 00 00 00    add    $0x80,%rsp
--> We have the lock... 
  4067dd:   44 89 c0                mov    %r8d,%eax
  4067e0:   c3                      retq
```